# Cannot instantiate SLIPSerial object used in OSC/SLIPSerial classes for Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-ide

Hey I'm trying to test out the CMAT/OSC library for Arduino and just want to get up and running sending SLIP encoded OSC messages. I've been able to observe the typical Serial monitor when sending OSC Messages that way, but I cannot seem to get the example code to compile:

```cpp
    #include <SLIPEncodedSerial.h>
    #include <OSCData.h>
    #include <OSCBundle.h>
    #include <OSCBoards.h>
    #include <OSCTiming.h>
    #include <OSCMessage.h>
    #include <OSCMatch.h>
    #include <SLIPEncodedUSBSerial.h>
    
    SLIPEncodedUSBSerial SLIPSerial( thisBoardsSerialUSB );
    // SLIPEncodedSerial SLIPSerial(Serial);
    
    
    void setup() {
      //begin SLIPSerial just like Serial
      SLIPSerial.begin(9600);   // set this as high as you can reliably run on your platform
    }
    
    void loop(){
      //the message wants an OSC address as first argument
      OSCMessage msg("/address");
      msg.add("Hello World\n");
    ;
      
      SLIPSerial.beginPacket();  
      msg.send(SLIPSerial); // send the bytes to the SLIP stream
      SLIPSerial.endPacket(); // mark the end of the OSC Packet
      msg.empty(); // free space occupied by message
      delay(20);
    }
```

Furthermore this is the output error I see:

```
error: 'SLIPEncodedUSBSerial' does not name a type; did you mean 'SLIPEncodedUSBSerial_h'?
   10 | SLIPEncodedUSBSerial SLIPSerial( thisBoardsSerialUSB );
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      | SLIPEncodedUSBSerial_h
exit status 1
'SLIPEncodedUSBSerial' does not name a type; did you mean 'SLIPEncodedUSBSerial_h'?
```

Could someone lend some clarity on what "thisBoardsSerialUSB" and "Serial" are in this context? I thought that the SLIPEncodedSerial / SLIPEncodedUSBSerial constructors simply take a reference. This might be trivial, but I am not sure how to properly instantiate these classes within the Arduino IDE.

Cheers!

Comment: What board are you compiling for?

Comment: `thisBoardsSerialUSB` is merely a placeholder for whatever the USB serial connection is for your board. Some have it as `Serial`, some `USBSerial`. It's up to *you* to put the right thing in.

Comment: there is `#if (defined(TEENSYDUINO) && defined(USB_SERIAL)) || (!defined(TEENSYDUINO) && defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__)) || defined(__SAM3X8E__) || (defined(_USB) && defined(_USE_USB_FOR_SERIAL_))  || defined(_SAMD21_) || (defined(__PIC32MX__) || defined(__PIC32MZ__))`

Comment: @Majenko Ah okay! I read into the example code a bit too literally! the board I'd like to use is the Adafruit Metro M0 Express, which uses a ATSAMD21G18 chip (an ARM Cortex M0+)

Comment: SAMD21 should work: `|| defined(_SAMD21_)`

Comment: @Juraj Yeah I had originally thought so as well! I found a weird quirk with installing the library via the provided library manager within the arduino IDE: it pulled an out of date version of the .cpp & .h files. Pulling from the git repo itself and referencing "Serial" as the argument to the constructor rectified the situation!